# Passing action type in function parameter

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to pass in the `insertError` function parameter the type of action that needs to take place.

```
  insertErrorClass(val, action) {
    val.classList.action(classNames.INVALID);
   }


Example:

  insertErrorClass(val, 'add') {
    val.classList.add(classNames.INVALID);
   }

  insertErrorClass(val, 'remove') {
    val.classList.remove(classNames.INVALID);
   }
```

I can do it using `if` statements, but was wondering if there was more efficient way of doing it.

Comment: If the value in action is a property on classList then you need to use square brackets.

Comment: you mean like val.classList[add](classNames.INVALID);
   }

Comment: No, [action], like any other property address.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function insertErrorClass(val, action) {
   val.classList[action](classNames.INVALID);
}
```

And calling your function as so:

```
insertErrorClass(val, 'add');
```

or

```
insertErrorClass(val, 'remove');
```